# jQuery automatic carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

My automatic carousel doesn't work. I tried using `setInterval` as you can see below but it still doesn't work. I really don't know why. It's syntactically correct and I think it ain't logically wrong either. Please help.

HTML:

```
<div class = "slidingPhotos" align="center">
    <div class = "slide active-item">
        <div class = "photo1">
            <img src = "Images/mainImage.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        <div class = "description">
            <h3> Welcome to O-Grocery! Your #1 Online Grocery Store </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "slide ">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "photo1">
                <img src = "Images/mainImage3.jpg"></img>
            </div>
            <div class = "description">
                <h3> You have a thousand products to choose from at O-Grocery! </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "slide">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "photo1">
                <img src = "Images/mainImage2.jpg"></img>
            </div>
            <div class = "description">
                <h3> You can guarantee 100% freshness of goods! </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class ="footer" align="center">
    <div class = "dots">
        <div class = "arrow-prev">
            <a href ="#"><img src = "Images/arrow-prev.png"></img></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="slider-dots">
            <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
            <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
            <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        </ul>
        <div class = "arrow-next">
            <a href ="#"><img src = "Images/arrow-next.png"></img></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
setInterval(function()
{
var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
var nextDot = currentDot.next();

if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
    nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
    nextDot = $('.dot').first();

currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active-slide');
setTimeout(function(){ nextSlide.addClass('active-slide').fadeIn('slow'); }, 500);

currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are there errors in the console? What do you expect it to do, and what happens instead? (*edit* - the JavaScript code has syntax errors; you should fix those first.)

Comment: What errors? It doesn't fade in and out automatically.

Comment: If that really is the code you're using, you'll see syntax errors reported in the browser console. If it *isn't* really the code, then you should get rid of it and replace it with the real thing.

Comment: How to replace it with the real thing?

Comment: I'll type this again: if that JavaScript code you posted in the question here is actually **exactly** the code that you are using, then your problem is that it contains syntax errors. Look at your browser developer console.

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error

```
setInterval(function()
{
var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
var nextDot = currentDot.next();

if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
    nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
    nextDot = $('.dot').first();
} // <- THIS is missing in your code

currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active-slide');
setTimeout(function(){ nextSlide.addClass('active-slide').fadeIn('slow'); }, 500);

currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
}, 5000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evilbuck/aj0nuyLk/